# Clojure, using arguments in matching

Tags: dictionary, clojure, arguments, match

So I've got a map like `{[1 1 1] "a" [1 1 2] "b"}`, etc. I have a function like:

```
(defn fetch [map x y z]
  (select-keys map (into []  (for [[k v] map
                                   :when (match/match [k]
                                                      [[x y z]] true
                                                      :else false)]
                               k))))
```

This doesn't seem to work though. It seems to only work when I hardcode in the values for `x`, `y`, and `z`. Any suggestions? I'd like something where I can supply an arbitrary number of arguments, and it'd give me all the keys that match that, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: If you have your heart set on `match`, you can write something like `(match [k [x y z]] [[a b c] [a b c]] true)`. But it seems silly for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend for

```
(fetch {[1 1 1] "a" [1 1 2] "b"} 1 1 1)
```

to return

```
{[1 1 1] "a"},
```

then filtering the entire key seq of the input map is extremely wasteful:

```
(conj {} (find {[1 1 1] "a" [1 1 2] "b"} [1 1 1]))
```

will do the job correctly and efficiently.

If you'd like to select entries from a map using a more interesting criterion, then you can filter it and use `into {}` to pour the result into a new map:

```
(into {} (filter (fn [[k v]] (even? k)) {0 "a" 1 "b" 2 "c" 3 "d"}))
;= {0 "a", 2 "c"}
```

`for` with `:when` is effectively the same thing, so if you prefer that syntax, you can of course use it. You'll just have to provide a predicate that does what you want. This should be more performant than using `select-keys` with a filtered key seq.

For selecting keys from your map given an arbitrary map of values for the coordinates, you could use

```
(defn fetch
  "Takes a map `m` keyed by vectors and a map `coords`
  keyed by indices into those vectors.

  Returns a submap of `m` that includes all on only the keys
  which agree with `coords` on the indices mentioned in `coords`."
  [m coords]
  (into {}
    (for [[k :as e] m
          :when (every? #(= (nth k %) (get coords %))
                  (keys coords))]
      e)))

(fetch {[1 1 1] "a" [1 1 2] "b" [1 2 1] "c"} {0 1 1 1})
;= {[1 1 1] "a", [1 1 2] "b"}
```

As for your `match` form not working: `match` is a binding form, so if you introduce variables in patterns, they will be bound to values extracted from the input if it matches the pattern, possibly shadowing locals from outer scopes.

Comment: True, it'd be wasteful if I just want one argument, but I'd like it to return a submap of all the keys that match the pattern, so (fetch {[1 1 1] "a" [1 1 2] "b"} 1 1) would return both "a" and "b". So for match, what you're saying is that [x y z] are getting bound to whatever is in k?

Comment: Yes re: `[x y z]` being bound to elements of `k`. Also, the pattern `[x y z]` matches an arbitrary three-element vector. If you substitute actual values in the pattern and match against `[1 2 3]`, say, then that pattern will of course only match the exact value of `[1 2 3]`. I'll update the answer with a comment on selecting keys from maps based on more interesting criteria in a second.

Comment: Updated. Continuing the above, your comment includes a call to `fetch` with only three arguments, but your sketch of `fetch` in the question text doesn't support that arity and it's not clear how you'd go about determining which parts of the pattern the ones should be taken to correspond to.

Comment: Updated with a working implementation of `fetch` that takes a map to be filtered and another map that guides the filtering.